# config.fish check if im in the home directory?

Tags: archlinux, fish

I want to create a if statement in the config.fish where I check if I the terminal session started in the /home/user directory.

like if I print pwd in the terminal.

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. What if you do or do not start in your HOME directory? What will you do next? You can use `pwd` in a function: `if [ (pwd) = $HOME ]; ...; end`

Comment: when i start the fish shell it runs the neofetch command that I only want to display if i start the terminal on the desktop, where the standard path equals /home/user. However when I use the terminal in my IDE or Code Editor I dont want to display the neofetch.

Answer (score 2):

It's more appropriate to check what Terminal application your shell is running in.

For example, on my Mac, I can do:

```sh
if pstree -p $fish_pid | grep -q '[i]Term2'
  echo running in my terminal app
end
```

And if I start a terminal in VS Code, that will output nothing.

---

The brackets in `'[i]Term2'` are a little trick to keep `grep` from matching the grep process.